# `require': no such file to load -- heroku/commands/pgbackups (LoadError) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am facing some strange problem. Before few minutes, every thing is fine but now. It becomes weird at my Test Server.

Error:

> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@dashboard/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in
>   `require': no such file to load --
>   heroku/commands/pgbackups (LoadError)

I am unable to trace the issue.

Comment: Even till today I could not get the solution. Is there anyone who has done this before ?

Comment: Have you tried removing and adding this addon? Did you interfere in any way with the load path?

Comment: No, I have not tried to add this addon. Infact I dnt have knowledge about this addon. Plz help me out if you have any idea about this... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The correct path should be [heroku/command/pgbackups](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/master/lib/heroku/command/pgbackups.rb).

(you have "commands", plural)

Comment: NO, I am not getting your point. plz clarify it. Thanks for the reply'

Comment: The file is at heroku/command/pgbackups but you have heroku/commands/pgbackups (command vs commands). In your require statement, you give the wrong path to the file.

Comment: Actually I dnt know the where is this folder. I made a search but I could not find this folder.

Comment: From the command line, you can find it with `"$(gem which heroku)/command"`, but you don't need to be concerned about where it is, you need to be concerned about how you try to load it into your app. You've only provided one line from the backtrace, so I can't tell where that happens, but follow the backtrace down until it gets into your app, then go there, and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This file is related to the Heroku addon for backing up postgres database. If you don't need it (like you said in the comments), just remove the addon:

```
heroku addons:remove pgbackups
```

If you need it though, try adding it back to see if it fixes things:

```
heroku addons:add pgbackups
```

Comment: But here, I am facing an issue while running this command::   WARNING: Unable to verify SSL certificate for api.heroku.com
To disable SSL verification, run with HEROKU_SSL_VERIFY=disable. Now what should I do to resolve this issue.. plz help me out.

Comment: I'm not sure. Either try to redeploy your app as a new heroku app or create a new question on SO.

Comment: Infact today I make fresh installation of whole project. Even though I am facing such issue. Previously it was resolved due to dependencies conflict of rake but this same procedure is done. but could not get the success.